# Ubuntu 15.10 root account login

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10, macosx

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 in the last version of VirtualBox on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.
I am facing some problems with the Mac OS X and I need to edit some files in the Mac's virtual hard disc!
So I mounted it, in the Ubuntu's virtual system! However, the disk's owner is root and I cannot edit or remove or add any files...

Is there any chance I could log in as root instead of my main account?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type open a terminal and run `sudo -H nautilus`. It'll open a file browser as root and allow you to edit those files.

Alternatively, you can open a terminal and run `sudo chown yourusername /path/to/file.txt`. For a folder: `sudo chown -R yourusername /path/to/folder`.

Comment: This won't work!!! I try to delete a file and I still can't! I try to change permissions and I get the message: "The permissions could not be changed"

Comment: @midkin did you try it?

Comment: I press properties to the file I need to delete! It now allows me to change the owner of the file and the access but if I choose anything it throws an error

Comment: @midkin Sorry, your question is a little unclear. You're mounting an HFS+ volume in Ubuntu. You can't gain write access to a journaled HFS+ volume on Ubuntu. You can use the Mac OS Disk Utility to turn of journaling for the drive before mounting it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Sry if am not clear! Am not ever sure what's going on.... I am almost sure I did this journaling thing before messing up my virtual Mac, since I was following steps...

Comment: @midkin (just a heads up: using exclamation marks makes others think you are shouting at them.) What is the error you get?

Comment: Any chance I could login as root (with the root account)?

Comment: @midkin yes, but you aren't going to see any difference.

Comment: I am trying to update my virtual mac from 10.10 to 10.10.4, problem is that after I patched them and before trying to start them again, I need to replace kexts and other files. I am trying to do so by mounting the virtual Mac hard disk in my virtual Ubuntu. However, this won't work as I cannot edit anything...

Comment: @midkin why not mount it in Mac?

Comment: Because I can't open my virtual Mac if I don't replace those files. Should I try to create a new virtual Mac and mount the old virtual Mac hard disc on the new virtual Mac system and try to edit those files from there?

Comment: I thought you said that you have the Ubuntu VM on a Mac.

Comment: Ah sry! Am not an English native speaker... I run on a Laptop with Windows 10... I also run 2 virtual systems on this laptop, one with virtual Mac and one with virtual Ubuntu. I tried to upgrade my virtual Mac from 10.10 to 10.10.4 and to do so I must edit the files from the virtual Mac hard disk. But to do so I cannot login to virtual Mac! Not untill i edit those files

Comment: Ah. Try this: http://superuser.com/q/330850/437627